Request status changed with tab change
I have a react app (a CMS panel) in which there is a clear cache button. pressing the button will trigger a request to the api of this panel and then the api handles the clearing of cache in the application.
The problem happens only when my client presses the button in the production build, they get a "ERR_NETWORK" after about 30 seconds and the request fails (the request itself is never received by api and the preflight gets 204.
We discovered that if they open a new tab in the browser right after clicking the button, the request will success in the background when you go the page and the cache is indeed cleared.
what could be causing the issue? What does this have to do with tabs.
they are using the latest version of firefox on windows 11.
